# Extracting text from application GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface, automation

Is there anyway to extract text from application UI by using C++ or C# (lets say like the text on the UI of steam launcher ) ? I need extract the text in order to do some automation of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Have a play around with spy++, it's a tool that comes with Visual Studio. If spy++ can dig down to see the UI elements then you can build a program that does the same.

Comment: I do see the window name but I am not able to view the message inside.

Comment: i actually tried another program (API Monitor v2) that can view process and I can see the message. But how do I grab the message in terms of a program ? Must I use a hook ?

Comment: Firstly, check if the application has a documented API that you can use. If not (which is likely), then intercepting the message using a message hook may be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it winth winapi, there are scripting languages that makes it easier:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Basicly you should locate somehow your control you want to read, spy++ is a good example, then read it either using its order in window hierarchy or class name.